# One word for "any time after this moment"

Tags: single-word-requests

I was just wondering if there is some sweet and apt word for the phrase "*any time after this moment*".

Comment: Do you really mean ***any** and **all*** times after this present moment? Including, say, some particular minute that will arrive in 1.5 billion years time? Your *"any time after this moment"* sounds suspiciously like the commonplace *"any time **now**"*, which of course means *"very soon"*. Whatever - I'm voting to close as General Reference (after upvoting the blindingly obvious *"future"*).

Comment: i'll answer this "later"

Comment: Could you use the phrase in the sentence to clarify which context you are intending to use it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Henceforth*** is a single word meaning *"any time after this moment"*. Exactly which word to use can depend on context, though.

Comment: A common business phrase is "going forward".

Comment: @MetaEd and Australian politicians, although "moving forward" was(?) common.

Answer (score 8):

I would consider using ***hereafter*** to fill your needs. It is often used in a legal sense but can equally be helpful in other contexts.

Answer (score 4):

What about simple, plain **future**?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for "henceforth?" Although it includes the present moment, it indicates inclusion of all moments in the future, including this one.

Answer (score 0):

*Later* is the first word that comes to my mind.

Comment: "Later" excludes "soon", though, so it's not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

*Henceforth* and *hereafter* are good.  How about *subsequently*?

Comment: *Subsequently* is not wrong, but it is not usually spoken of from the perspective of the present. It's normally used to refer to a time after *that* moment, not *this* one. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Hereon, henceforth, hereforthwith, henceforthwith, hereafter. Unless it needs to be specified because of prior events, it's actually redundant to state it.
Some more: forward(ly), afterwards, post-present (I cheated) and later.

Answer (score -1):

What about the adverb ***prospectively***?

Answer (score -1):

What about the term **immediately**?